# Browser() initialization

Tags: python, spynner

So I installed this module according to these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner.git
cd spynner
python setup.py install
```

And I get this kind of error, and I don't have any clues what could be wrong.

> > > import spynner
> > >
> > > browser1 = spynner.Browser()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spynner-1.11dev-py2.7.egg/spynner/browser.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.jquery = open(os.path.join(directory, self._jquery)).read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spynner-1.11dev-py2.7.egg/spynner/javascript/jquery-1.5.2.js'
```

Comment: Make sure you have `jquery-1.5.2.js` and it's available in that path.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, in that folders where missing 3 jquery files, and I added them manually. Now it works.